# How to replace src for data-src with regex?

Tags: php, html, regex

i have whole page in html and before output i want to replace all img src for data-src
i am using

```
  return (preg_replace('~<img[^>]*\K(?=src)~i','data-',$buffer));
```

but this doesnt match for example

```
<img alt="alt" src="src">
```

it only matches when the src is first

```
<img src="src"
```

I cant get it to work like i want, can you help me edit this pattern to do what i need?

Comment: Use html parser instead

Comment: i have to use regex

Comment: Why do you have to use regex? Homework?

Comment: yes i want to change src to data-src

Comment: @JiříKaštovský It works  - https://regex101.com/r/mwvphb/1

Answer (score 2):

I think this should work for you:

```
preg_replace("/(<img[^>]*)src=/", "$1data-src=", '<img alt="alt" src="src">');
```

`$1` is a backreference representing the first matched group (everything in the parentheses of the pattern).

Comment: it is only replace the first match,, how to replace in multiple tags?